# Integers for intervals with both increasing and decreasing values in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, range

I am trying to find a way to get all integers between two numbers, including end and start point, where first number might be smaller, bigger or the same as the second number, while keeping the order.

So far numpy.linspace seems as the best solution and I could think of a workaround for range function, but I still have a feeling that I am missing something obvious and there might be a better solution.

linspace solution:

```
import numpy as np

tps = ((7, 2), (0, 3), (9, -2), (-3, 4), (5, 5))

for tp in tps:
    print(np.linspace(tp[0], tp[1], num=abs(tp[0] - tp[1]) + 1, dtype=int))
```

range solution:

```
tps = ((7, 2), (0, 3), (9, -2), (-3, 4), (5, 5))

for tp in tps:
    if tp[0] < tp[1]:
        print([num for num in range(min(tp), max(tp) + 1)])
    else:
        print([num for num in range(min(tp), max(tp) + 1)][::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

from less to more:

```
for tp in tps:
    print(sorted([num for num in range(min(tp), max(tp) + 1)]))
```

the inverse situation:

```
for tp in tps:
    if tp[0] < tp[1]:
        print([num for num in range(min(tp), max(tp) + 1)])
    else:
        print([num for num in range(max(tp), min(tp) - 1, -1)])
```